# Visual Studio: How to breakpoint at a yet-unknown location?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, visual-studio

I'm working on a rather complex, multithreaded app that is not owned by any one person.  Out of many MessageBoxes that are correct, there's at least one that needs a different message.  I can get to it easily through the UI, but I have no idea where it is in the code.  If I pause the debugger at that point, it goes to the Application.Run(...) method call and the Call Stack is empty.

How can I tell where that MessageBox is?

Can I have it break as soon as I close the MessageBox and take me to the code that did it?

Or perhaps pause all threads and let me see which one is close to a MessageBox.Show(...) that looks about right?

I'm using VS2008.

---

This code has a LOT of MessageBoxes with varying patterns.  Some use MessageBox.Show(...) while others use owner.Invoke(new MessageBoxShowDelegate(MessageBox.Show),...).  A very few include the message directly; most either passthrough an exception message or get their strings from a database.

I'm just another one in a long string of people that have modified this code without much internal documentation, so there's no overall structure that I can see.

Comment: Do an "Edit/Find and Replace/Quick Find/Look in Entire Solution" for a portion of the error message displayed in the dialog.  That should locate the message box unless you're just parroting an exception message.  If that doesn't work, do a Quick Find for "MessageBox" and breakpoint every one of them.  That should find it unless you have a huge number of them (unlikely).

Comment: Umm, actually, yes, there are a LOT of them.  No overall structure to this code that I can see.  Some parrot exceptions, some are hard-coded, some pull their message strings from a database, etc.

Comment: I wonder if this is a better question for SO as it's somewhat a technical non-conceptual question (I could tell you how to use a memory dump to find the call stack that generates that, or using ILSpy you could find the string literal in the string table and find references in the rest of the IL to that string table offset, or you could use an old app by the name of SPY++ to look at the windows heap to find a reference to it's `wHnd`, but none of these are conceptual things...)

Comment: A lot of message boxes in an application is a warning sign.  Message boxes are by far the most expensive UI element there is; you should be using them very rarely. There really shouldn't be all that many, and the few that are relevant to your particular problem should be confined to a specific part of the code.

Comment: I agree, but such it is and everyone's scared to mess with it.  Horror stories about all the work required to implement seemingly minor features while keeping backwards compatibility into the stone age, etc.  To be honest, I'm not really sure what they're talking about, but I'm probably not going to convince them.

Answer (score 5):

Run your program in the Visual Studio debugger.

When the message box appears, pause the debugger.

Check all your threads, and the thread showing the MessageBox should be halted somewhere in the callstack at the line where the message box is called.

This is true for both WPF and WinForms as far as I can tell. If you aren't seeing anything in your call stack, you are either on the wrong thread, or have other problems like the message box caller being in a library you can't debug.

[image: Pause Button]
[image: Call stack]

Comment: Is this true? I can never remember if the thread actually halts, or the message pump just generates these things and then moves on to others so you'd have to dig through the message pump to actually find the reference to this, no? I guess it depends on whether they generated it modally non-asynchronously... The message pump is the actual creator but that doesn't mean the user code that invoked this call wouldn't be blocking... good point.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I usually get a call stack, but maybe the code is dumping the call stack and rethrowing, or he can't get a breakpoint in the correct thread.  Something like that.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: assuming the message boxes are 'true' `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` messageboxes, and not some half-baked reinvented copy with the same name, then I am 99% sure they always block.

Comment: I'm sure I can put a breakpoint at the spot that does it...if I knew where it was.

Comment: @AaronD: You don't need a breakpoint. When the messagebox appears, just alt-tab to visual studio and hit pause.

Comment: How can I see all the threads after I click the pause button.  I only see one Call Stack, and it only has one entry: `Application.Run()`

Comment: @whatsisname  Aha!  That's what I was looking for!  Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I would also like to add that while the answer works for the person asking, this might not work for everyone: unless it changed recently, the Express Edition of Visual Studio [cannot debug multi-threaded programs](http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/01/09/visual-studio-express-limitations-lead-to-bad-practices/).